# Django admin search by field of an external table via 'foreign key' too slow

Tags: python, django, performance, django-admin

I have two models in Django:

```py
class Dog(models.Model):
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class Bark(models.Model):
    date_of_bark = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    pet = models.ForeignKey('Dog',
                            related_name='bark_dog',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In admin form, I want to search all the Barks of a specific Dog:

```py
class BarkAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'date_of_bark', 'pet')
    search_fields = ('pet__nick', )
```

In my database, every Dog has millions of Barks.
The problem is that every search takes a lot of time:
**Load times (aprox):**

> Load of table :   Instant
>   Search results: 15 seconds

In order to improve the time, I ordered the search field:

```py
class BarkAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'date_of_bark', 'pet')
    search_fields = ('pet__nick', )
    ordering = ('pet__nick',)
```

And now we have these **load times (aprox):**

> Load of table :   15 seconds
>   Search results: Instant

How can I improve both times simultaneously?

### EDIT : Using get_search_results function

Based of [Django admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results), the *get_search_results* function can be overwritten to improve the search like this:

```py
class BarkAdmin(BaseAdmin, BaseActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    paginator = MyPaginator
    list_display = ('id', 'date_of_bark', 'pet')
    search_fields = ('pet__nick', )

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(BarkAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        # Get the pet_ids with the searched nick
        pets = Dog.objects.filter(nick__contains=search_term)
        # Pick only the Barks with pet in the set
        queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(pet__in=pets)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

But I am doing something wrong, because now we have these **load times (aprox):**

> Load of table :   Instant
>   Search results: 15 seconds

Answer (score 1):

My first aim would be to tune the query as far as possible. I see that you've indexed the nick field.

I would guess that the fact that you have a load time of 15 seconds on either method shows that the query still takes the same time but the table loading is delayed by a sort.

You can tune the query to make the search more efficient for what you are trying to do. I'm not sure how you want the search to work i.e. any barks where nick contains any of the characters entered in the search.

The following documentation (change for your Django version) can help you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

**Edit:**
You could try optimising the two queries into one using select related. A possible solution although untested. It may also require an additional annotation for counting:

```
queryset = self.model.objects.select_related('Dog').filter(Dog__nick__contains=search_term)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/#retrieve-everything-at-once-if-you-know-you-will-need-it

It would be good to know what the current queries generated look like i.e. are lots being fired off for this query causing many small queries?

I can add instructions for logging to the console what queries are running.

Comment: Maybe the solution is around the "get_search_results" function. I am going to research about this.

Comment: @MouTio if my answer is correct can you accept it please. You will also get points for accepting an answer. :-)

Comment: your answer is useful. Due to this I gave you a vote up. I researched and edited my post with the results. Nevertheless, it didn't improve anything of my problem. I still need a valid solution. That is the reason to not accept your answer.

Comment: OK, My apologies, I didn't see your edit. It would be good to see what the queries Django has generated look like. I shall also add an edit in for a different solution.